# how to say ant that configuration files is in that folder

Tags: java, ant, slf4j, logback

I have project structure like shown below, and I am trying to write ant build file. My problem is how I can say build.xml that configuration files of logback is in conf folder?

project hierarchy

```
project
  | - - - src
  | - - - lib
  | - - - conf
           | - - - logback.xml
  | - - - ant
           | - - - build.xml
  | - - - rsc
           | - - - input.txt
```

I have wrote

```
<path   id="classpath">
        <fileset    dir="${lib.dir}"
                    includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>


<!--- init used to create a requirred directories -->               

<target name="compile"  depends="init">
    <javac  srcdir="${src.dir}" 
            destdir="${build.dir}/classes">
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <!-- ? what should be written -->           

</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `conf.dir`property that points to `${base.dir}/conf`:

```
<!-- Absolute path to logback conf file -->
<property name="logback.conf.file.abs.path" location="${conf.dir}/logback.xml"/>
```

*run*-target:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java failonerror="yes" classname="your.main.class.name.Here">
        <arg line="-Dlogback.configurationFile=${logback.conf.file.abs.path}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the file with an startup parameter on ant call

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/logback.xml
```

if you use an antrunner you might say

```
c:>antrunner -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/logback.xml build.xml
```